# MassEmailMessage and "Too many Email Invocations: 11"

Tags: email, bulkification, send-email, massemailmessage, bulk

I try to test bulk-scenario, but there is an error msg "System.LimitException: Too many Email Invocations: 11". Can I use MassEmailMessage or I need to use only SingleEmailMessage with adding it to the List?

Comment: You can only call Messaging.sendEmail 10 times per transaction, can you please share your code so that we can help you better ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the MassEmailMessage class, but you do need to create a list and send them all at once:

```
Messaging.Email[] emails = new Messaging.Email[0];
for(SObject record: someRecordList) {
  emails.add(generateEmailFor(record));
}
Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
```